# How do I change the URL of my Shopify app?

Tags: shopify

I am stuck in a very basic thing.

Initially when I had created my app, it was named - "abc"; url - "https://apps.shopify.com/abc";

Now I need to change the name to - "xyz", but the url remains the same. Is there any way I can change the url to - "https://apps.shopify.com/xyz". Or I will have to create another app with name - "xyz", so that it picks up the required url?

Answer (score 0):

You can either speak to [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) crew to change that url (which is the one for public access to Shopify AppStore), or you can eventually create the new app on your [partners dashboard](http://www.shopify.com/partners/?ref=microapps) with the desired name.

Answer (score -2):

No need create another App. you can change your app's proxy path via shopify partner account.

Login into you shopify partner account, go to `Apps -> Your Application -> App proxy` change the path, now your application can be accessed via this new url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think App's proxy solves some different purpose - http://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/application-proxies#add-a-proxy.